# How to zoom properly using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am trying to make zooming work on my D3 graph.

I have currently found a solution to making my zoom work whilst having an ordinal x-axis, but I have trouble having the x-axis zoom match with the circle and square elements. The more you zoom in, the more "out of place" they become.

Here is a JS fiddle to my current code, where I've attempted to implement my zoom.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/c794g977/3/

I would like to know how to properly implement my zoom so that the elements don't go out of place.

Below I've pasted my zoom functions:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomHandler);

function zoomHandler() {
    var translate = zoom.translate(),
    scale = zoom.scale();

    var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(width * (1 - scale), translate[0]));
    var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(height * (1 - scale), translate[1]));

    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

    //svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.selectAll(".circleNodes")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");

    svg.selectAll(".squareNodes")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");

    svg.select(".x.axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+","+(height)+")")
        .call(xAxis.scale(x.rangeRoundBands([0, (width * d3.event.scale)],1 * d3.event.scale)));

}
```

Any help is greatly appretiated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the transform altogether. All the adjustments can be done by modifying the ordinal scale, accounting for the translation there.

```
x.rangeBands([d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[0]+(width * d3.event.scale)], 1)
```

(Switch to using `rangeBands()` instead of `rangeRoundBands()` which eliminates the jitter.)

Then you just have to adjust the positions to all the circles and squares and re-render the axis based on this new scale.

```
svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
circle.attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d);})
square.attr("x", function(d){ return x(d) - squareSize/2;})
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c794g977/6/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! As you might've noticed I have added clipping path to my graph, the reason for this was to prevent the axis going out of the "box" they start in. As soon as you start zooming it moves towards the left and right and out of their original "bos" or position. In any case thanks for this response, it helped out a lot!